# What is the best practice for a while loop where the end condition may not be meet?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

What is the best practice for a While Loop where the end condition may not be meet? Really looking for a language independent answer, but if it helps I am coding in Java Script.

I am looping through an HR database and walking through the hierarchy, looking for a value that will meet the condition. In theory, the condition should be achieved every single time. However in the one-in-a-million chance that the condition is not achieved; I don't want to leave the code open to an infinite loop.

My solution is to simply added a integer that increments with each loop; and will break the loop when the count meets a hard-coded value.

I don't like this solution, it feels dirty. I also don't like leaving the loop open to the possibility of an infinite loop.

What have you done in this scenario?

Comment: Use some large counter to break out of it

Comment: time based, event based ...

Comment: I personally use the counter while developing, too. But for a live scenario you should try to find a different design for your loop, so you can handle all logically possible situations inside it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure HR has not developed the world's first infinite database. Can't you count on the loop ending once you get through it?

Comment: Well, there is a SQL call that is modified and re-ran with each loop, and is based on the data retrieved from the previous loop. In theory, if bad user data is in the DB; the loop may find itself inside an infinite loop.

Comment: can you assert/validate on the data before entering the loop? or assert/validate while in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration that you would like to enter the iteration at least one time, the best practice is to use do/while loop. You do what you want, then check if the condition is met.

While the condition is met, You will continue doing what you need, meaning continue looping. This way you can track your loop and trace it to exact point.

There is no way the end condition won't meet.